# Error when saving to MySQL when field contains ' character

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a form with PHP that saves a variable to a MySQL database. That form worked on a VPS, but when trying it on another VPS it gives an error when trying to write to the database when the field contains a ' character. So the same PHP code works on 1 VPS when the field contains a ' character, but not on the other VPS.

Here it works: http://www.zoekmachineoptimalisatie.us/test.php
and here (it's the other VPS) it gives an error: http://www.onzebruidsfotograaf.nl/test.php

My form:

```
<?php
$hostname = "localhost"; //host name
$dbname   = "xxxxxxxx"; //database name
$username = "xxxxxxxx"; //username you use to login to php my admin
$password = "xxxxxxxx"; //password you use to login
$conn     = new MySQLi($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) { //if the submit button is clicked

    $title  = $_POST['updatetitle'];
    $bookid = 1;
    $update = "UPDATE test SET Title='$title' WHERE BookID = " . $bookid;

    $conn->query($update) or die("Cannot update"); //update or error
}
?>


<?php
$bookid = 1;
$sql    = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE BookID = '" . $bookid . "'";
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$query = getenv(QUERY_STRING);
parse_str($query);
?>

<h2>Update Record <?php echo $bookid;?></h2>

<form action="" method="post">
    <?php

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>

        <textarea name="updatetitle" cols="100" rows="30"><?php echo $row['Title']; ?></textarea>

        <table border="0" cellspacing="10">

            <tr>
                <td><INPUT TYPE="Submit" VALUE="Update the Record" NAME="Submit"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</form>

<?php
if ($update) { //if the update worked

    echo "<b>Update successful!</b>";

}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do not use `query` when variables are involved with the SQL statement. Use `prepare`(, `bind`) and `execute`. See http://php.net/mysqli.prepare

Comment: It's called [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com), and you should learn about it before you go any farther with this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An unescaped quote in your query will produce a syntax error. Instead of building the SQL fully your own, make use of SQL variables for your PHP variables with a *Prepared Statement*:

```
if (isset($_POST['Submit'])) { //if the submit button is clicked

    $title  = $_POST['updatetitle'];
    $bookid = 1;

    $update = $conn->prepare('UPDATE test SET Title = ? WHERE BookID = ?;');
    $update->bind_param('sd', $title, $bookid);
    $update->execute();
}
```

One of your servers has [Magic Quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) enabled and the other doesn't. Magic Quotes is now considered undesirable and is deprecated, it automatically escapes input. You should turn off Magic Quotes and use a parameterised query/prepared statement instead - then there is no need to escape anything and it prevents SQL Injection.

Paramterised queries are supported by the [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and PDO APIs.

Comment: Thank you both for your help!  The problem was Magic Quotes which was disabled in one of the VPS'es...  I will try to find a solution, after reading about SQL injection ;)

Answer (score 0):

because the single quote breaks the query statement. In order to prevent from it or from `SQL Injection` you need to use `PDO` or `MySQLI` extension. For more infor, see the article below

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: `mysql_*` are not *alternatively*, they are deprecated. Apart from that OP uses mysqli.

Comment: @hakre yep, last paragraph removed.